# Linkedin API request fails "Resource rest does not exist" when get sharesid

Tags: linkedin-api

Good Morning,

I'm trying to get shareid of my test publication on Api Linkedin my request is:

```html
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/rest/posts/shareUrn(urn:li:share:6947445733109194752)?X-Restli-Protocol-Version=2.0.0&LinkedIn-Version=202206
```

I also have my token but I don´t understand the reply:

```html
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource rest does not exist",
    "status": 404
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you either go with 'V2' versioning or 'rest' versioning. The endpoints with headers should be (in python):
V2:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/rest/posts/shareUrn/' 
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    }
```

Rest:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/rest/posts/shareUrn/' 
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'LinkedIn-Version': REST_VERSION,
    }
```

where REST_VERSION is something like '202212'.

Optionally (not all LI endpoints accept it) you can add to the headers info about protocol:

```
"X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "/rest" from the endpoint.

Include "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" and "LinkedIn-Version" in the header of the request.

Make sure all the query params in the request are in correct format.

Goodluck!